# use same controller code with multiple views

Tags: php, symfony, view, controller

I am using symfony 5.4 and i have a controller that manage multiple routes and return a view.

Now i would like to create another controller that has the exact same logic in all the pages but that return another view.
Here is an exemple of what i have actually :

```php
class KioskController extends AbstractController
{

 public function manualRegistration(
                                ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
                                Request $request, 
                                Session $session,
                                LoggerInterface $logger,
                                MyWebservice      $myWebservice,
                                AppointmentService $appointmentService)
    {
        
       /*
       *  page logic i want to re-use in another in another controller
       */
        return $this->render('path/to/view.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView(),'myVar'=>$var1, 'myArray'=>$arr]);
    }

    // other routes 

}
```

My initial idea is to create an abstract class that will extend `AbstractController` and return an array with all the elements that will be use in the view (form and other variables / arrays) like so :

```php
abstract class AbstractKioskManager extends AbstractController
{

 protected function manageManualRegistration(
                                ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
                                Request $request, 
                                Session $session,
                                LoggerInterface $logger,
                                MyWebservice      $myWebservice,
                                AppointmentService $appointmentService)
    {
        
       /*
       *  page logic i want to re-use in another in another controller
       */
        return  ['form' => $form->createView(),'myVar'=>$var1, 'myArray'=>$arr])
    }

}
```

and then use this abstract controller for the 2 or more controllers that will display the different views :

```php
class KioskController1 extends AbstractKioskManager
{

 public function manualRegistration(
                                ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
                                Request $request, 
                                Session $session,
                                LoggerInterface $logger,
                                MyWebservice      $myWebservice,
                                AppointmentService $appointmentService)
    {
        
       $viewParams = $this->manageManualRegistration($doctrine,$request,$session,$logger,$myWebservice,$appointmentService);
        return $this->render('path/to/view1.html.twig',$viewParams);
    }

    // other routes

}


class KioskController2 extends AbstractKioskManager
{

 public function manualRegistration(
                                ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
                                Request $request, 
                                Session $session,
                                LoggerInterface $logger,
                                MyWebservice      $myWebservice,
                                AppointmentService $appointmentService)
    {
        
       $viewParams = $this->manageManualRegistration($doctrine,$request,$session,$logger,$myWebservice,$appointmentService);
        return $this->render('path/to/view2.html.twig',$viewParams);
    }

    // other routes

}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Yes.
Use [Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

Then you just have to inject it to be able to re-use your logic in all the controllers you want, like that :

```php
public function myFunction(Myservice $myService): Response
{
    $myService->doSomething();

    return $this->render('path/to/view1.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: is it really ? can you explain a bit more why ?  with your way, i have to put in the constructor of the service all the dependencies (request, session, formBuilerInterface, etc...) even if i don't need them all in all the routes and with your way, i can't as easily redirect to another route

Comment: You shouldn't pass the whole world in your Service. Use your service for generic, reusable things (like registration, or authentication or whatever) and use your controller for specific things (like routing based on the service response, or rendering the view, or whatever). That's what it's for. 
You asked for a cleaner way, I gave you one. Just my two cents. But if you prefer to chain inheritances... It's up to you.